# Export C++ class from main program to DLL

Tags: c++, class, dll

With C++, i'm trying to use a class declared on my main program instance to be used with on DLL. It's a lot of examples to a class from DLL to use on main program, but I need the other way. For now, a simple declaration is ok, but my next step will be use a static class from main program on DLL.

For knowledge, I'm using MinGW 3.4.5 on Windows 10.

For an example I'm trying to generate 3 files:

- tst_class.lib
- tst_library.dll
- tst.exe

And the source code files are:

- tst_class.h

```cpp
class ON_MAIN tst_class {
public:
     tst_class(char *);
    ~tst_class(void);
};
```

- tst_class.c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define ON_MAIN  __declspec(dllexport)
#define ON_DLL   __declspec(dllimport)

#include "tst_class.h"

tst_class::tst_class(char *source)
{
    printf("new tst_class() from %s\n", source);
}
tst_class::~tst_class(void)
{
    printf("delete (tst_class *)\n");
}
```

- tst_library.c

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

#define ON_MAIN  __declspec(dllimport)
#define ON_DLL   __declspec(dllexport)

#include "tst_class.h"

ON_DLL void tst(void)
{
    tst_class *t = new tst_class("library");
    delete t;
}
```

- tst.c

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define ON_MAIN  __declspec(dllexport)
#define ON_DLL   __declspec(dllimport)

#include "tst_class.h"

typedef void (__cdecl *f_pointer)(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tst_class *t = new tst_class("main");
    delete t;

    HMODULE module = LoadLibrary("tst_library.dll");

    if(module != NULL) {
        printf("Dll loaded\n");

        void *function_pointer = (void *)GetProcAddress(module, "tst");

        if(function_pointer != NULL) {
            f_pointer function = (f_pointer)function_pointer;

            function();
        }

        FreeLibrary(module);
    } else {
        printf("Can't load dll\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To compile them:

- `g++ -c tst_class.c -o tst_class.o` **OK**
- `ar cr tst_class.lib tst_class.o` **OK**
- `g++ tst_library.c tst_class.lib -o tst_library.dll -shared` **Error**

And here I've got this error message:

> .../ccpg0mO9.o:tst_library.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to '_imp___ZN9tst_classC1EPc'
>   .../ccpg0mO9.o:tst_library.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to '_imp___ZN9tst_classD1Ev'

But following to the last step...

- `g++ tst.c tst_class.lib -o tst.exe` **OK**

What I'm doing wrong with compiling/linking the library?

The executable works well. Not loading the library of cource, because it not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defines are not quite right. The form of the `declspec` is generally

```
#if BUILDING_MYDLL
  #define MYDLL_EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define MYDLL_EXPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And for the definition of the class

```
class MYDLL_EXPORT tst_class {
public:
     tst_class(char *);
    ~tst_class(void);
};
```

Then when building and linking the dll code, you use a command line define for `BUILDING_MYDLL` (e.g. `-D BUILDING_MYDLL`) or you define `BUILDING_MYDLL` in a header file that is internal to the dll (e.g. in Visual Studio based solutions that was often stdafx.h).

Here is [another answer that is related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574423/3747990).

Comment: Ok. I got this. My problem with `undefined reference` is gone. Now I can do more tests, but what I figured out is: the class code is on the .lib file.  What I want is the class code is on the main program, and with new versions, the DLL will use the new class source.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it works. That sounds like a new question. Write it up with the code samples, expected outcomes etc. and post it as a new question.

Comment: I'll make another question. But the solution is only for the `undefined reference`. The main question is: Use class (code) from main program on DLL.

Comment: Explore pure virtual base classes as an interface. You may need to shift them into a third dll that will be shared with both the current dll and the exe.